# Bootstrap4 multiple data-toggle with tooltip and button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Since it it actually (in Bootstrap 4) not possible to set multiple data-toggle at once i found this solution to get it work.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Flexible Arbeitszeiten"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Home-Office"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Betriebliche Altersvorsorge"><i class="fas fa-shield-alt"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Gesundheits- und Sportangebote"><i class="fas fa-heartbeat"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Firmen-Laptop"><i class="fas fa-laptop"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Firmen-Smartphone"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Kantine"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Kinderbetreuuung"><i class="fas fa-child"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Firmenwagen"><i class="fas fa-car"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Gute Zuganbindung"><i class="fas fa-train"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Gute Zuganbindung"><i class="fas fa-subway"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Gute Busanbindung"><i class="fas fa-bus"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Weiter- / Fortbildungen"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Mitarbeiterbeteiligung / -boni"><i class="fas fa-percent"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Jobticket"><i class="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Sabbatical"><i class="fas fa-stopwatch"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-toggle="buton" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Mitarbeiterevents"><i class="fas fa-glass-martini"></i></button>
```

an the in my JavasScript i init the tooltip toggle this way

```
$("[data-hover='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

So it works finde but i have one problem. If i click the button and the button got the active state the tooltip is shown the whole time since i click anotehr button. But the tooltip should disappear when i move the cursor out of the button focus, like on the normal tooltip behaviour. How can i fix this?

When i do not click any button and move only the cursor over the button the tooltip is appearing and disappearing as it should.

Here is a Screenshots of the problem:
[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior, and it seems to work as expected in my dev env. Could you please post your code that reproduces the phenomenon? Thanks!

Comment: thanks for reply. i added some more code above. That's all. The problem is: if i click a button it will be enabled (like on the left side of my screenshot) ´. Additionally the tooltip ist shown, which is first right. Then when i move the mouse cursor over the other buttons (wthout clicking them) i got the tooltip for the hovered button, but the tooltip of the clicked button did not leave. Maybe this is the behaviour which is wanted?! but for my use case the tooltip of the clicked button should disapear when i hover the other buttons.

Comment: I think I understand the problem, however unfortunately I still can't reproduce the problem with the provided markup.

Comment: Could you provide your working code?